# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to -2} (3x+7)^{\frac{1}{x^2-4}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x\to -2} (3x+7)^{\frac{1}{x^2-4}}$$

$$y=\lim_{x\to -2} (3x+7)^{\frac{1}{x^2-4}}$$

$$\ln y=\ln \left(\lim_{x\to -2} (3x+7)^{\frac{1}{x^2-4}} \right)$$

$$\ln y=\left(\lim_{x\to -2} \frac{\ln(3x+7)}{x^2-4}\right)$$

Applying L'hopital

$$\ln y= \left(\lim_{x\to -2} \frac{\frac{3}{3x+7}}{2x}\right)$$

$$\ln y=-\frac{3}{4}$$

$$y=e^{-\frac{3}{4}}$$

Is there a way to solve it using something like $(3x+7)^{\frac{1}{3x+7} \cdot (3x+7) \cdot\frac{1}{x^2-4}}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Let assume $$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow -2}(3x+7)^{\frac1{x^2-4}}$$

We can see $$\ln L=\lim_{x \rightarrow -2}\frac{\ln(3x+7)}{{x^2-4}}$$

$$\frac{\ln(3x+7)}{{x^2-4}}=\frac{\ln(1+3(x+2))}{{(x-2)(x+2)}}$$

If we use Taylor expansion at x+2, we get

$$\frac{\ln(3x+7)}{{x^2-4}}=\frac{\ln(1+3(x+2))}{{(x-2)(x+2)}}=\frac{3(x+2))}{{(x-2)(x+2)}}-\frac{(3(x+2)))^2}{2{(x-2)(x+2)}}+O((x+2)^2) \rightarrow -\frac3{4}$$

This gives $L=e^{-\frac34}$

Or if not using Taylor expansion, let's use substitution $x=\frac13y-2$

$$\frac{\ln(3x+7)}{{x^2-4}}=\frac{\ln(1+y)}{{y}}\frac1{(\frac19y-\frac43)}$$

Keep this in mind, $$e=\lim_{h\to 0} \left(1+h\right)^{1/h}$$

The limit $L=e^{-\frac34}$

Comment: My view is that Taylor series expansions do not avoid l'Hôpital's Rule so much as they subsume it under the convergence of power series.  I'm sure you can see the otherwise close parallel between your development and the proof already offered in the Question.

Comment: Added a solution using an alternative way other than Taylor expansion.

Comment: Nice, that is the sort of (change of variable) approach the exercise might have been targeting.

Comment: I can only agree. I consider the change of variable method to be far more interesting and insightful than Taylor or L'Hospital. Just a personal fave.

Answer (score -4):

Taking log we have: $\dfrac{\log(3x+7)}{x^2-4}$, and you can use L'hospitale rule for this.

Comment: which is actually what the op did

Comment: Yes, but this is probably the fastest and most efficient way.

Comment: well yes but the op is asking if we can use another method